# Invalid use of aggregation function in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is the query where I am trying to get some data but in this particular query its giving me error. The query is something that on the level of nodes I am checking that the particular property is being used in any other node(here n4), as if property is being used we can't delete that particular property.

```
 Match(n1:TESTDATA{nodeName:'HierarchyName'})-[:hasSubClass]->(n2)-[:hasPropertyGroup]->(n3)
    -[:containsProperty]->(n4) with n2 ,n4
    match (n2)-[:hasInstance]->(n5)
    where n2.elementType='class' 
    and not(n4.status = 'Deleted') 
    and n4.nodeName <>'Property' and count(n5)=0
return n4.nodeName
```

> Invalid use of aggregating function count(...) in this context (line
>   6, column 38 (offset: 277)) "and n4.nodeName='Property' and
>   count(n5)=0"

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid use of aggregating function count(...)

yes, you cant use `count` like this, either use `count` with `WITH`

and another solution change your query

```
Match(n1:TESTDATA{nodeName:'HierarchyName'})-[:hasSubClass]->(n2)-[:hasPropertyGroup]->(n3)-[:containsProperty]->(n4) 
WHERE n2.elementType='class' 
AND NOT (n2)-[:hasInstance]->()
AND NOT(n4.status = 'Deleted') 
AND n4.nodeName <>'Property' 
WITH n4
return n4.nodeName
```

Comment: AND NOT (n2)-[:hasInstance]->(n5) is giving error Variable `n5` not defined (line 3, column 32 (offset: 195))
"AND NOT ((n2)-[:hasInstance]->(n5))"